# Pytorch network built with subclasses not learning

Tags: python, class, deep-learning, pytorch

As part of a project I'm currently trying to train a network with an architecture similar to the
[image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILqJl.png), using Pytorch module. The network I am trying to build is a Variational AutoEncoder-like. My problem is that when I use sub-classes such as below to define my layers, the backpropagation doesn't work and the network does not learn anything, despite working fine with predictions.

At the start of my project, I went around this problem by defining just the one VAE class with attributes self.encoder = nn.Sequential(...) and self.decoder = nn.Sequential(...).
My project is now more complex and I need to use such an architecture, which requires this problem to be solved. I wanted to know if anyone had some experience with such a problem. I've thought the problem could be linked to getters and setters, however I can't figure how to configure a setter for state dictionnary. Also, I tried removing the underscore before the subclasses, but that didn't change anything.

I also checked that loss wasn't none and that require_grad = True, and  [both these were verified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qscwM.png)

```
class _Dense(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, inDim, hDim, zDim, dropout, type):
    super(Dense, self).__init__()
    self.xDim = inDim
    self.zDim = zDim
    if type == "encoder":
        self.dense = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Dropout(p=dropout),
                nn.Linear(inDim, hDim),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(p=dropout),
                nn.Linear(hDim, hDim),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(p=dropout),
                nn.Linear(hDim, hDim),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(p=dropout),
                nn.Linear(hDim, 2 * zDim))
    else: 
        self.dense = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(zDim, hDim),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(hDim, hDim),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(hDim, hDim),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(hDim, hDim),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(hDim, inDim),
                nn.Sigmoid())

def forward(self, x):
    return self.dense(x)

class _convBlock1D(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, inDim, inChannels, outChannels, kernelSize, stride = 1, padding = 0, dilation = 1):
    super(convBlock1D, self).__init__()
    self.inDim = inDim
    self.inChannels, self.outChannels = inChannels, outChannels
    self.kernelSize, self.stride, self.padding, self.dilation = kernelSize, stride, padding, dilation
    
    self.outDim = floor(
        (self.inDim+2*self.padding-self.dilation*(self.kernelSize-1)-1)/self.stride + 1
        )

    self.conv = nn.Conv1d(self.inChannels, self.outChannels, self.kernelSize, stride = self.stride, padding = self.padding, dilation = self.dilation)

def forward(self, x):
    return self.conv(x)

class _deconvBlock1D(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, inDim, inChannels, outChannels, kernelSize, stride = 1, inPadding = 0, outPadding = 0, dilation = 1):
    super(deconvBlock1D, self).__init__()
    self.outDim = inDim
    self.inChannels, self.outChannels = inChannels, outChannels
    self.kernelSize, self.stride, self.dilation = kernelSize, stride, dilation
    self.inPadding, self.outPadding = inPadding, outPadding

    self.inDim = floor(
        (self.outDim+2*self.inPadding-self.dilation*(self.kernelSize-1)-self.outPadding-1)/self.stride + 1
        )

    self.deconv = nn.ConvTranspose1d(self.inChannels, self.outChannels, self.kernelSize, 
                                    stride = self.stride, padding = self.inPadding, output_padding = self.outPadding, dilation = self.dilation)

def forward(self, x):
    return self.deconv(x)


class _Conv1D(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, inDim, latentDims, nBlocks = 3):
    super(Conv1D, self).__init__()
    inChannels = 1
    outChannels = 1
    kernelSize = [5, 9, 11]
    self.xDim = inDim
    layers = [_convBlock1D(inDim, inChannels, outChannels, kernelSize = kernelSize[0])]
    for i in range(1, nBlocks):
        outDim = layers[-1].outDim
        layers.append(_convBlock1D(outDim, inChannels, outChannels, kernelSize[i]))
    layers.append(nn.Linear(layers[-1].outDim, 2*latentDims))
    self.layers = layers
    self.conv = nn.Sequential(*self.layers)

def forward(self, x):
    return self.conv(x)


class _ConvTranspose1D(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, inDim, latentDims, nBlocks = 3):
    super(ConvTranspose1D, self).__init__()
    inChannels = 1
    outChannels = 1
    kernelSize = [5, 9, 11]
    self.xDim = inDim
    layers = [deconvBlock1D(inDim, inChannels, outChannels, kernelSize = kernelSize[0])]
    for i in range(1, nBlocks):
        outDim = layers[0].inDim
        layers = [deconvBlock1D(outDim, inChannels, outChannels, kernelSize[i])] + layers
    self.layers = [nn.Linear(latentDims, layers[0].inDim)]+layers
    self.conv = nn.Sequential(*self.layers)

def forward(self, x):
    return self.conv(x)

class VAE(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, xDim, hDim, zDim, dropout, type = 0, bbl=None):
    super(VAE, self).__init__()
    self.xDim = xDim
    self.hDim = hDim
    self.zDim = zDim
    self.dropout = dropout
    
    if bbl is None:
        nBands = [self.xDim]
    else:
        nBands = get_continuous_bands(bbl)

    encoderDict, decoderDict = {}, {}
    params = dict((id, (nChannels, zDim)) for id, nChannels in enumerate(nBands))

    if type == 0:
        for modelID, modelParams in params.items():
            encoderDict[f'model-{modelID}'] = Dense(modelParams[0], self.hDim, self.zDim, dropout = self.dropout, type = "encoder")
            decoderDict[f'model-{modelID}'] = Dense(modelParams[0], self.hDim, self.zDim, dropout = self.dropout, type = "decoder")
        self.encoder = SpectralWrapper(encoderDict)
        self.decoder = SpectralWrapper(decoderDict)

    elif type == 1:
        for modelID, modelParams in params.items():
            encoderDict[f'model-{modelID}'] = Dense(modelParams[0], self.hDim, self.zDim, dropout = self.dropout, type = "encoder")
            decoderDict[f'model-{modelID}'] = ConvTranspose1D(modelParams[0], zDim)
        self.encoder = SpectralWrapper(encoderDict)
        self.decoder = SpectralWrapper(decoderDict)

    elif type == 2:
        for modelID, modelParams in params.items():
            encoderDict[f'model-{modelID}'] = Conv1D(modelParams[0], zDim)
            decoderDict[f'model-{modelID}'] = ConvTranspose1D(modelParams[0], zDim)

    self.encoder = SpectralWrapper(encoderDict)
    self.decoder = SpectralWrapper(decoderDict)

def kld(self):
    prior = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(
        torch.zeros_like(self.posterior.loc), torch.ones_like(self.posterior.scale)
    )
    kld = torch.distributions.kl.kl_divergence(self.posterior, prior).mean()
    return kld

def nll(self, x):
    return - self.likelihood.log_prob(x).mean()

def lossFunc(self, x, beta = 1):
    return self.nll(x) + beta * self.kld(), self.nll(x), self.kld()

def forward(self, x):
    tmp1, tmp2, B = {}, {}, 0
    x = x.unsqueeze(1)

    # Encoding
    for modelId, model in self.encoder.models.items():
        res = model(x[:, :, B:B+model.xDim])

        B += model.xDim
        tmp1[modelId] = res[:, :, :self.zDim]
        tmp2[modelId] = res[:, :, self.zDim:]

    keys = list(tmp1.keys())
    mu = torch.cat([tmp1[keys[i]] for i in range(len(tmp1))], dim=-1)
    logvar = torch.cat([tmp2[keys[i]] for i in range(len(tmp2))], dim=-1)

    # Sampling
    self.posterior = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(mu, torch.exp(logvar / 2))
    z = self.posterior.rsample()
    
    # Decoding
    tmp3, B = {}, 0
    for modelId, model in self.decoder.models.items():
        res = model(z[:, :, B:B+model.xDim])

        B += model.xDim
        tmp3[modelId] = res
    
    keys = list(tmp3.keys())
    out = torch.cat([tmp3[keys[i]] for i in range(len(tmp3))], dim=-1)
    self.likelihood = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(x, torch.ones_like(x))

    return z.squeeze(), out.squeeze()
```